# Scala GraphLoader.edgeListFile (NumberFormatException)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im loding edges of a graph from file

```
val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "comb.txt")
```

Hoverwe its throwing error.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "116374117927631468606"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I think it accepts only integer node values. How do i . fix this

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/graphx/GraphLoader.html

Comment: can you update with sample input data?

Answer (score 0):

the api document clearly states the following comments

> > `/**
> >        * Loads a graph from an edge list formatted file where each line contains two integers: a source
> >        * id and a target id. Skips lines that begin with`#`.
> >        *
> >        * If desired the edges can be automatically oriented in the positive
> >        * direction (source Id is less than target Id) by setting`canonicalOrientation`to
> >        * true.`

And `116374117927631468606` value is certainly big for it to be an integer as the [official site](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int$.html) says

> > `final val MaxValue: Int(2147483647)
> >     The largest value representable as a Int.`